# TypeError: turn_left() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I can't get past this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 687, 
in eventfun
    fun()
TypeError: turn_left() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I'm using Turtle.

```
class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        Sprite.__init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.speed = 4
        self.lives = 3

    def turn_left(self):
        self.lt(45)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.rt(45)

    def accelarate(self):
        self.speed += 1

    def decelarate(self):
        self.speed -= 1

turtle.onkey(Player.turn_right, "Right")
turtle.onkey(Player.turn_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(Player.accelarate, "Up")
turtle.onkey(Player.decelarate, "Down")
turtle.listen()
```

Comment: You haven't created an instance of your class. You're just referencing the methods directly on the class, so there is no `self` object.

Answer (score 0):

The `self` object gets initiated when an instance of a class is created, which you aren't doing, therefore it's not finding the *required* argument `self`.

Try this:

```py
P = Player(spriteshape='your-shape', color='your-color', startx='start-x-value', starty='start-y-value)

turtle.onkey(P.turn_right, "Right")
```